# Neovim Kickstart config "E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_editor.lua:0: attempt to compare two table values" everytime I open neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I am getting an error every time I start up neovim in my terminal. I am able to continue past the error and use neovim but am annoyed at getting every time and wondering what is not configuring correctly.

[Error that displays when I open neovim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOlAy.png)

[lines 150-179 in my init.lua file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjMOf.png)

[neovim version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lmky.png)

I am using Ubuntu jammy.

I was expecting to run this command from the kickstart repository readme `git clone https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim.git "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}"/nvim` and have a fully functional neovim configuration but I keep getting this error.

I was also expecting to find a comparison of two table values of the `init.lua` file after reading the error but all I see is a keymap. And it seems to keymap fine on line 159.

I googled it and found somewhat similar stuff and thought I needed to update to a newer version to neovim. after updating to the latest version I still get this error.